# I had stored a smart contract instance in MySQL as string. How to convert it back to solidity instance?

Tags: python, flask, solidity

I stored the smart contract instance which written in Solidity inside the MySQL database. 
`contract_instance = eth_provider.contract(
                    abi=contract_abi,
                    address=contract_address,
                    ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)`

The value stored is liked Ex: web3.contract.ConciseContract object at 0x00000187148C9F98

When I retrieve the value in Python flask and access the smart contract function, the error shown `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getCustomerList'`
.

How to convert the value from str back to smart contract instance?

Answer (score 0):

Only `contract_address` are different in all the contracts. Store the address only and compiled the contract each time the user needs to use it